# How to share a variable between multiple Views/XIBs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've read several similar threads, but can't seem to figure this out - sorry.
I've got a project with multiple Views, including a ViewController, several "sub" views, and a NavigationController. I'd like to have an array that is accessible from any of the Views, so that I can populate a TableView or a TextField, etc. I'd like the array to be modifiable from any View that can access it.

Right now I have this in the xxAppDelegate.h file:

```
NSMutableArray *listOfHeadings;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listOfHeadings;
```

And in the xxAppDelegate.m file I populate the array:

```
listOfHeadings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[listOfHeadings addObject:@"Heading 0"];
[listOfHeadings addObject:@"Heading 1"];
```

But I can't seem to access the array from other .m files.
How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current design you have, you can get ahold of the AppDelegate pointer using:

```
AppDelegate *dPtr = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Then you can access your array using the property:

```
[dPtr.your_array objectAtIndex:i];
```

But I would highly recommend using a Singleton design pattern to manage your global objects.

Comment: @ipmcc  I tried this option in my view .m file but get the error at the declaration: "Use of undeclared identifier AppDelegate"

Comment: @AJ. I tried this option in my view .m file but get the error at the declaration: "Use of undeclared identifier AppDelegate"  (thanks @ipmvcc)

Comment: By AppDelegate I meant your Applications Appdelegate class name.

Comment: @AJ. Duh. I'm switching to a Singleton anyway - it seems a lot cleaner. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes Singleton is the way to do it. You are Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since you put your array in `xxAppDelegate`, you can access your array from any other class like this:

```
#import "xxAppDelegate.h"
//...
NSMutableArray *array
= [(xxAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] listOfHeadings];
```

Comment: I tried your code, substituting my actual names, and had a few errors (Xcode 4.2), so I first changed "NSApp" to "UIApplication". I now get the error "No known class selector 'delegate'" (pointing to UIApplication) and "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" (pointing to xxAppDelegate).

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot that it’s different on iOS. (My code was for the Mac). I have now modified my answer; feel free to try it out now.

Comment: Still not there -I have the import statement, but I'm still getting: "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" (pointing to xxAppDelegate)

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that you could access your app delegate/root controller's property for the array, that would violate principles of encapsulation. Rather than define a single property that all your subview/controller classes will access, pass the array to each class that needs it (you'll still only have one array in memory, and each class will access the same array) at an appropriate time (eg, instantiation).

Another option would be to create an application wide singleton class to provide the array to interested callers.

Comment: Your first suggestion is far better than the second. If you tell a view controller everything it needs to know to do it's job, it won't have any external dependencies. That means more flexible, more reusable, more testable, and more maintainable.

Comment: @isaac So you feel I should implement something similar to what is shown below by ipmcc or Enchilada ? Also, how do I give credit for this answer if you responded with a solution and someone else responded with sample code?

Comment: @isaac Sorry, one more thing - I assume this solution would also be the proper way to access/pass data from a file (xml for example), database, or other disk-based source?